# ¿Como pasar el resultado de una función a un input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

No he podido con este problema, tengo una función que me crea el lote en base a la hora y fecha y una letras que son fijas; lo que quiero es que lo que se muestra en el *documet.write* en el input del html

```
<script>
    function lote(){

        miFechaActual= new Date()
        dia = miFechaActual.getDate()
        mes = parseInt(miFechaActual.getMonth())+1
        ano = miFechaActual.getFullYear()
        turno =miFechaActual.getHours()

        if(turno>=5 && turno<13){

         turno=1

        }else if(turno>=13 && turno<21){
          turno=2

        }else if (turno>=21 && turno<5){

          turno=3

        }

         $(document).write("AG"+dia+mes+ano+turno)   //<-- el resultado de esto lo pueda llevar al value del input en html  


    }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Y que comportamiento tiene este código?

Comment: No uses `$(document).write()`, porque eso solo agrega texto al final del documento, en su lugar, selecciona el campo y asigna el valor: `$('#id_del_campo').val("AG"+dia+mes+ano+turno)`

Comment: en java imprime el  esto AG231120201 esto es lo que que imprime este codigo y este valor lo quiero llevar a un input de html  
<input type="text" name="lote" value="aqui quiero llevar lo que java me imprime=>

Comment: <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="lote No" maxlength="50" name="lote" id="lote" >

Comment: con el id no se muestra el lote en el campo del id :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Lo que debes usar es el método `val` para agregar contenido al input y de esta manera llevar el texto mas la fecha a este mismo.
- No determinante pero usa *template strings*, hacen que el código sea mas simple de constituir y leer
- Recupera al input por medio de su id a través del selector de JQuery así:

  ```
  $("selector").......
  ```

Código

```
    <input type="text" id="elemento">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      let miFechaActual= new Date();
      let dia = miFechaActual.getDate();
      let mes = parseInt(miFechaActual.getMonth())+1;
      let ano = miFechaActual.getFullYear();
      let turno = miFechaActual.getHours();
    
            if (turno>=5 && turno<13) {
              turno=1;
            } else if (turno>=13 && turno<21) {
              turno=2;
            } else if (turno>=21 && turno<5) {
              turno=3;
            }
    
             $("#elemento").val(`AG ${dia}${mes}${ano}${turno}`)   
    </script>
```

**Enlaces de interés**

- [elemento input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input)
- [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)
- [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write)
- [selector de id en JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: gracias men si me funciono  :)